# Replace coaxial cable

Tags: walls, cables, coaxial-cable

I have some coaxial cable on my wall, I need to replace it with a different cable, but when I pull the cable, it doesn't move at all.

I know in the US it's common that these cables are stapled, but where I live that is not common at all, these are brick walls, and the cables are inside plastic tubes. I think the cables have been there for a very long time and now they are stuck, is there a way to pull those cables?

Comment: Just asking, but why do you need to replace the cable? Is it damaged? If you are thinking you need to replace it with something like Cat-6 for internet?   There is a method to re-use old coax for ethernet/internet access called MoCA. You put MoCA adapters on each end of the coax and then it can support TCP/IP, ethernet protocols.  Depends of course upon your exact situation, but it's something you might want to check out.

Comment: Coax cables are usually only stapled where accessible in crawl spaces to keep them from hanging down and outside the structure. With the coax in nonmetallic flex I would not expect it to be stapled but possibly stapled or taped at a splitter other than exterior or crawl space runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would not be stapled in conduit anywhere in the world.

Check very carefully that you have found both ends of the **same** cable/conduit. The most likely reasons for "being stuck" are:

- that you have the same cable, but you've missed a spot where it comes
  out of one conduit and goes into another (possibly being attached to
  something),
- **or** you have two different cables and the other end of the one you are trying to move is fastened to something outside the conduit,
- **or** you've missed a "pull point" (removable access cover or junction box) providing access to the cable inside the conduit so that you're not trying to
  pull it around more than 360 degrees of bending.

Typical access points involve a relatively sharp bend which you will NOT be able to pull around, since you are supposed to remove the cover and pull from the open access point.

If you think you have eliminated those possibilities, you could put a vacuum cleaner (wet or wet/dry type - a "shop vac") at one end, and verify that you really do have the correct conduit at the other end by noticing the air getting sucked in there, and then you could apply some wire pulling lubricant to the open end, and allow the vacuum to pull it into and through the conduit. That should help the wire to move, if it's not actually bound up by a sharp turn at an access point you have not opened to pull from.